# Android Firebase How to check if there are pending requests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app on android using firebase, and I am using the firebase database.

with firebase db, the user can send data to the db even when there is no internet (offline), and then when there is internet again, and the user is online, the messages are beeing sent to the db.

I want to check, if the user was offline and sent messages, and then got back online and there are mesages that are beeing send - I want to check for it, and if so I don't want the user to see a specific activity until all the data is finished sent to the db.

Is there a way that firebase has a simple command that check for pending results? or should I use a SahredPreference variables to store when a user sent something offline and then when got back online - remove those SharedPreferences after the data is sent - but and if so, how can I check if there is data that beeing send?

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can listen to `.info/connected` to get the status of the connection to the database [Detecting Connection State](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state)

Comment: There is currently no API to check if there are pending writes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280502/firebase-synchronisation-of-locally-modified-data-handling-errors-global-stat